# Calendar Date SSIS Microsoft BI

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

i want  to fill table dim_Date(idDate,date,year,month,trimester,weekNumber,week,day) from a calendar and date with  this format "year/month/day hh:mm
 can you please help me 
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Im making some assumptions here since you didnt say what the format of the date format is in (i assumed a varchar) and you didnt specify what weeknumber and week was...so I assumed week of year and week of month:

```
-->set up data for example
create table dummy_date_table
(dummy_date varchar(50))
go
-->insert dummy data(assuming you have these somewhere as text?)
insert into 
dummy_date_table (dummy_date) values
('2010/11/01 01:22'),
('2013/06/02 03:16'),
('2012/07/03 05:32'),
('2011/01/04 06:04') 
go

-->create date dimension based on your logic
create table dim_Date(
idDate int, -->pk
date datetime, -->full date
year int,-->year of date
month int,-->month of date
trimester int,-->trimester 1,2,3
weekNumber int,-->week number in year
week int, -->week number in month
day int --.day part of date
)

go

-->used for primary key|date|year|month|trimester|weeknumber|week|day
declare @i int=1, @date datetime, @year int, @month int, @trimester int, @weeknumber int, @week int, @day int
-->cursor to insert our data
declare date_inserter cursor for

select 
 convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10)),
 datepart(year,convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))),
 datepart(month,convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))),
 case  
  when datepart(month,convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))) <5 then 1
  when datepart(month,convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))) >4 and    datepart(month,convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))) <9 then 2 
  else 3 
 end,
 datepart(ISO_WEEK,convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))),
 DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))), 0), convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10))) +1 ,
 datepart(day,convert(datetime,left(dummy_date,10)))
from
dummy_date_table;

open date_inserter;

fetch next from date_inserter into
  @date,
  @year,
  @month,
  @trimester,
  @weeknumber,
  @week,
  @day

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

insert into dim_Date 
select @i, @date, @year, @month, @trimester, @weeknumber, @week, @day
set @i+=1;

fetch next from date_inserter into
  @date,
  @year,
  @month,
  @trimester,
  @weeknumber,
  @week,
  @day
END
-->Cleanup
CLOSE date_inserter
DEALLOCATE date_inserter
go
-->Look at data
select * from dim_Date
```

Results:

```
idDate  date                    year    month   trimester   weekNumber  week    day
1       2010-11-01 00:00:00.000 2010    11      3           44          1       1
2       2013-06-02 00:00:00.000 2013    6       2           22          2       2
3       2012-07-03 00:00:00.000 2012    7       2           27          1       3
4       2011-01-04 00:00:00.000 2011    1       1           1           2       4
```